# How to debug function in PyCharm called from IPython in web browser (Chrome)?

Tags: python, pycharm

The scenario is as following.

**For the data processing work, I write the complex algorithms in *.py files with PyCharm. Then, I call these functions and plot results in IPython in the web browser. I want to debug the function in *.py file using PyCharm when I run the function from IPython.  I can do this using PyDev, but I do not know how to do this in PyCharm.**

In PyDev, I can debug the function called from IPython in Chrome in the following way.

step 1. open the python file in PyDev (for example, test.py ). 
 step 2. set the breakpoint from code in PyDev editor

### test.py

```
using pydevd 
def my_add(a, b):
   a = 1
   settrace()              ## break point here 
   b = 2  
   return a+b
```

step 3. In PyDev, open debug server  (push a button)

step 4. In browser of the IPython page, run the code to call `my_add()`.

```
import test
my_add()
```

step 5.PyDev will stop at the breakpoint
    PyDev will enter step-by-step debug model. Then, I can debug as normal python file.

**Question:** When using PyCharm (2016.2), I cannot find similar function to open debug server.
Can anyone give me some suggestions on how to debug code in PyCharm called from IPython in the browser (Chrome).

Comment: Did you check out https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.3/using-jetbrains-chrome-extension.html

Comment: It has solved like this. When setting the breakpoint by "pydevd.settrace()", the URL and port number should be set as the same in the Remote debug configure dialog. For me, I call pydevd.settrace('localhost', port=3897) . In PyDev, I just use the default value, just call pydevd.settrace(). Hope this will help the people have the similar problem. 
Thank you so much for your help.   (more details, see https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000088230-How-to-debug-the-function-in-PyCharm-called-from-IPython-in-web-browser-Chrome-)

Comment: Well great. You could add this comment as an answer to your own questions as well Leo